# Download Submodules on github.com

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I host a project on github.com. My project have some git submodules.

One can clone a project with submodules with `git clone --recursive`, but since my audience are not developers, but people who never heard of git, I wonder if there is a way to make it possible to download project with submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "download package" by uploading whatever you want along with the submodules and providing the link to it.

Example:

https://github.com/frapi/frapi/downloads

You can go to "Downloads" page of your repo upload such packages.

Comment: Sadly this feature has been deprecated: https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads